# what does user.isAnonymous in firebase Authentication signify ? I mean in which case the user is Anonymous?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

what does user.isAnonymous in firebase Authentication signify ? I mean in which case the user is Anonymous?

```
final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

assert(!user.isAnonymous);
final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

That `isAnonymous` property for a user is `true` when that user signed in to Firebase Authentication with the [anonymous identity provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). This means the user didn't provide any credentials, and their sign-in not based on any check or knowledge of the user.